# gotext: extract failed: pipeline: golang.org/x/text/message is not imported

Tags: go, localization, translation

I am trying to run the following command from within my `template.go` file:

```
//go:generate gotext -srclang=en update -out=catalog.go -lang=en,de_DE,es_MX,fr_CA,pt_BR
```

I am expected to get a catalog.go generated, but instead, I get the following error:

```
gotext: extract failed: pipeline: golang.org/x/text/message is not imported
template.go:3: running "gotext": exit status 1
```

I do have the following import in the `template.go` after the generate command:

```
import (
    "time"

    log "github.com/sirupsen/logrus"
    "golang.org/x/text/message"
)
```

I've tried to move the import before the `generate` command. I've also tried to run `generate ./...` from within the root of the project. I've also tried to run `gotext` by itself, but it's the same error message.

I also found the following thread on github:
https://github.com/golang/go/issues/26312
I've tried what was suggested there, but it didn't seem to have solved the issue either.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have solved the issue by running `rm -rf vendor/golang.org/x/text` command from the root of the project. Of course for things to work, I also needed to have gotext installed. This can be done by running `go get golang.org/x/text/cmd/gotext`.

I believe the issue could be solved if binaries of `.../text/message` are installed in the `GOPATH/bin` as well